# Implicit intersection and IFERROR()

Tags: excel, vba

VBA:

```
myCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(MIN(IFERROR(FIND({""d.o.o."",""DOO"",""D.O.O"",""doo"",""D.O.O."",""D O O""},RC[-5]),"""")) > 0, LEFT(RC[-5],MIN(IFERROR(FIND({""d.o.o."",""DOO"",""D.O.O"",""doo"",""D.O.O."",""D O O""},RC[-5]),""""))-1)&""  "", RC[-5])"
```

actual formula in cell has @ added before IFERROR():

```
=IF(MIN(@IFERROR(FIND({"d.o.o.","DOO","D.O.O","doo","D.O.O.","D O O"},L2),"")) > 0, LEFT(L2,MIN(@IFERROR(FIND({"d.o.o.","DOO","D.O.O","doo","D.O.O.","D O O"},L2),""))-1)&"  ", L2)
```

and evaluates to #VALUE!

Step by step shows `IF(MIN(@{"","",12,"","",""}) > 0` ... before evaluating `MIN("")` to #VALUE

When I remove @ manualy, the formula works. Also works if using Formula2R1C1, but I need the VBA to be compatible with pre-365 Excel.

What to do?

Comment: paste as text like xyxyIF(... then change xyxy to = after.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks, nice hack, but will impact performance over 1000s of rows. I would prefer to understand if there is a different approach, because it looks like Excel shot itself in the foot with this new feature

Comment: User `.Formula2R1C1`

Comment: You could test one cell first using CallByName passing "Formula2". If that returns a 438 error, you are not in a version that supports dynamic arrays.

Comment: @ScottCraner that one doesn't work in previous versions

Comment: @Rory , is there a way to test for 438 error in code? I couldn't find how.

Comment: Use an error handler and then test `err.number`. I'd do it in a separate function.